# DownloadManager directly into external storage directory

Tags: android, path, android-download-manager

I'm trying to download a big zip file directly inside the external storage directory, for example

```
"/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.vexdev.audioguida.app/files/data"
```

i guess i should be using

```
DownloadManager.Request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(path, fileName)
```

but i don't know how to provide it with a path that is consistent across different android devices.

AND i'm also trying to get a path to access this file later, like this:

```
File file = new File(path + fileName);
```

i'm asking here because i know that those two methods are expecting different rooted paths, because i tried to provide a path like this:

```
Application.getAppContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()).getAbsolutePath();
```

but the DownloadManager was not putting the files where the File constructor was searching it later. (It was downloading in the wrong directory actually!)

I'm looking for a way to download those files directly in the right directory, without having to move them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i guess i should be using DownloadManager.Request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(path, fileName)

Not for the location you suggested. The closer match would be [`setDestinationInExternalFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationInExternalFilesDir%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

> but i don't know how to provide it with a path that is consistent across different android devices.

There isn't even a path that will be consistent within one device, as different accounts will use different paths. For example, the path you typed into your question *might* be used on *some* devices for *some* accounts, but the details will vary.

> i'm also trying to get a path to access this file later

That is covered in the `DownloadManager.Request` documentation:

- `setDestinationInExternalFilesDir()` maps to `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context`
- `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()` maps to `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` on `Environment`

> i tried to provide a path like this

That is not how you use `getExternalFilesDir()`. Please read [the JavaDocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29) to see what valid values are for the parameter to that method. `getDataDirectory()` is not a valid value.

Comment: You're right i should have looked better at the documentation. I was hoping for an answer like yours.